# /proc/net/dev unit conversion

Tags: linux, type-conversion

I'm looking at the file /proc/net/dev and wondering about unit conversion of the receive bytes value.

Here's the part of the file I'm contemplating:

```
Inter-|   Receive
 face |bytes
  eth0: 7060880392
```

ifconfig uses /proc/net/dev to produce the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet 
          ...
          RX bytes:7060880392 (7.0 GB)
```

That's what I don't understand.  Given that the unit of the value is in bytes (rather than bits), I would have expected to convert to GB through divisions of 1024.  7060880392/1024/1024/1024 = 6.6GB.  But clearly ifconfig has used divisions of 1000 to convert from B to GB.

Can someone explain why they did this?  I know bandwidth is generally expressed in bits; perhaps the labeling in /proc/net/dev is incorrect in referring to the unit of the value as bytes?  I checked the manpage for proc, but there's not a lot of detail on this file.

Comment: Is there any reason to think the decision was anything other than arbitrary?

Comment: In computing, the prefix _G_ is inconsistently used for 10^9 and 2^30. However, the former is actually correct, and for network traffic the latter doesn't make sense. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: I could arbitrarily decide how to use this information.  Given that it's a volume bandwidth, which is most commonly measured in bits, and that ifconfig performs unit conversions with divisions of 1000, I'd be inclined to do the same.

I suppose I should clarify: in asking why, I'm seeking to understand how i should perform these conversions accurately rather than arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

The term `GB` represents 10 base, while `GiB` represents 2 base (1024). Read more on wikipedia: [Binary prefix.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

I'd make an educated guess that the implementer chose to use GB instead of GiB because the relevant info is how many bytes were sent/received, rather than their division to fit the "computerized" calculation.

Comment: people often use GB/Gb/gB/GiB inconsistently when considering bit vs byte.  More importantly, the file clearly says byte.  I don't want to guess; I want to find a documentation that explains what I perceive to be a discrepancy.

Comment: Counting GiB is necessary when discussing storage space, not quantity. Storage space is measured by sectors (which are base 2 in size, for example a 512B HDD sector, 4096B for FS cluster/block). Quantifying HDD space as a stream is done using GB (base 10), for which you count the amount of total bytes available on the drive. When counting network bytes, you count the stream size (or quantity), and not the space required to store it as a file. I couldn't find any article to back me on this, however I can't think of any place which uses GiB which is not storage/file related.

Comment: do these number reset at some point ? Are these lifetime numbers ?